# How to make line join circle node perfectly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was connecting a line to a circle node, when I noticed that (under a microscope) the line does not meet the circular node's radius perfectly. This wouldn't normally be visible, but with an ultra thick line and small node radius, the gap becomes obvious.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-3pt) -- (0,3pt);
\draw (0.3,-3pt) -- (0.3,3pt);
\node (leftEnd) at (0,0) [draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt] {};
\node (rightEnd) at (0.3,0) [draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,fill=white] {};
\draw[ultra thick] (leftEnd) -- (rightEnd);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ thick line joining two small circle nodes]

How do I make the line meet without any gap?

EDIT: Ideally the circle nodes should be empty, so as to allow lines behind them to be visible or not. I have updated the MWE and picture to reflect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anohter option is to simply connect the `center` points and then redraw with a `fill=white` option, or, as per marmot's suggestion, you can do the drawing all at once:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=0.5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{Node Style/.style={thick, draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (leftEnd)  at (0,0)   [Node Style] {};
\node (rightEnd) at (0.3,0) [Node Style] {};

\draw [ultra thick] (leftEnd.center) -- (rightEnd.center);

\node (leftEnd)  at (0,0)   [Node Style] {};
\node (rightEnd) at (0.3,0) [Node Style] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] 
       (0,0)   node[Node Style] {} 
    -- (0.3,0) node[Node Style] {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works in isolation, but my use case is more general. I am graphing linear inequalities and use the circle nodes for endpoints of an inequality, eg. [this one](https://i.imgur.com/W1gv8lk.png).

Comment: @onomou This answer still works if you draw these things on the background layer. Load `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` and do `\begin{scope}[on background layer] \draw[ultra thick] 
       (0,0)   node[Node Style] {} 
    -- (0.3,0) node[Node Style] {}; \end{scope}`.

Comment: @onomou: If marmot's suggestion or one of the answers here does not work for you, please update the question with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) the reflects your use case more accurately.

Comment: @PeterGrill Good point. I have updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the shorten value ,`shorten >=1.5pt,shorten <=1.5pt`, or use the arrows.meta library to get the same result.

RESULT: Zoom 1000%

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Circle[fill=none,length=3.5pt,line width=0.5]}
]
\node (leftEnd) at (0,0) [draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt] {};
\node (rightEnd) at (0.3,0) [draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt] {};
\draw[ultra thick,shorten >=1.5pt,shorten <=1.5pt] (leftEnd.center) -- (rightEnd.center);
\draw[ultra thick,<->,shorten >=-1.75pt,shorten <=-1.75pt] (0,-10pt) -- ++(0.3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `shorten >=` is no longer documented in the 3.01a manual of Tikz, can you document it more fully in order to make your solution understandable for those who do not have the Tikz 1.18 manual?

Comment: @AndréC: Hmmm. Wow, did not know that that was going to be removed? It is still used in may examples though.

Comment: @PeterGrill I see that it is used in many examples, but the documentation is no longer given, which hinders the understanding of the answer. Thus, it would be nice if its use were explained in the answers that use it.

Comment: `shorten > =` as such is not described, but manual 3.0.1a uses it in many examples, especially when describing graphs.

Comment: @Zarko The examples in the documentation will never replace clear documentation such as the 1.18 manual, which is fortunately still available (until when?) here: https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf

Comment: @AndréC, thank you for the link. yeah, this manual is 11 year old, short and (very) nice. this description seems to be lost when was arrows.meta adding. a big pity!

Answer (score 7):

to the some line width it helps if you set in nodes' style `outer sep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
circ/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt, outer sep=0pt}
                    ]
\node (leftEnd)  [circ] {};
\node (rightEnd) [circ] at (0.5,0) {};
\draw[ultra thick] (leftEnd) -- (rightEnd);
\draw[line width=6pt, gray, semitransparent] (leftEnd) -- (rightEnd);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot, i know this! also i mentioned in answer that proposed solution wok to a some line width   :-) . however, i didn't mention to which ratio between circle and line width ...

Comment: This seems to be the simplest method, not needing any extra tikzlibrary or scoping.